# How to browse the iPhone HEIC images on Windows without the automatic conversion to JPG?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, iphone

I am not sure whether it was always like it. If I plug in the iPhone, I can check for example:

```
This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\202308__
```

with all of the images of that month. But the HEIC files are converted to JPG if I browse this iPhone folder on Windows, in the Windows Explorer. These JPGs have double the size of HEIC.

How to get the folder with the HEIC images instead?

The aim of this question is not how I can show the images at all. It is just about the problem that the file types are JPGs instead of HEIC, which looks like this:

[image]

And instead of those JPGs, I need the HEIC files.

Comment: [Simple associate the file extension with the Photos application.](https://www.howtogeek.com/345504/how-to-open-heic-files-on-windows-or-convert-them-to-jpeg/#how-to-view-heic-files-in-windows-10-39-s-photos-app).  Additionally, make sure, you are not trying to preview the image, while it's synched to iCloud. I have determine there is some weird behavior there.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not synch to iCloud. I do not want to have JPG files. I can open HEIC files on Windows with the needed decoders, that is not the aim here. Instead, I need to save the HEIC files on the computer like they are saved on the iPhone or in its backup. The aim is to copy all of the HEIC files to a Windows folder and delete those copied files on the iPhone. Now, I only see those HEIC files as JPGs. Thus, they get converted at lightning speed to JPG, which is nice if I want to look at them quickly, but which I do not need for this task.

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to achieve. I am able to preview HEIC images from the current revision of the iPhone, without converting them to jpg all I had to do was associate the file extension with the Photos application

Comment: @Ramhound I think this is still a misunderstanding, perhaps it is my English. I do not need to convert or preview anything. My problem is that the files are already JPGs as soon as I plug in the iPhone and check the files in there, even though on the iPhone itself, they are HEIC. I can even get those HEIC files with a 3rd party tool, extracting them from the backup. Thus, I know that they are HEIC files, but they show up as JPGs on Windows. I checked your remark, my HEIC files are already associated with the Photos app (I also tested it with "Paint" instead). I made the question a bit clearer.

Comment: What software is converting those images? My images on my iPhone and synchronized to my Windows machines is HEIC

Comment: @Ramhound Your remark was the good question that was missing here, though I have just found an answer without it. The software that is doing the conversion is on the iPhone, which was not clear to me. I thought it would be a Windows setting. Therefore, this question might be better on Ask Different SE instead. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer to this is in the settings on the iPhone;** it is not a Windows setting that converts the HEIC to JPG. I found this at [How to stop iPhone from converting HEIC to JPEG when AirDrop-ping to laptop](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251309845).

On the iPhone, go to *Settings → Photos* and scroll to the bottom.

In the *Transfer to Mac or PC* section, tap "Keep Originals" to prevent the media from being converted to JPEG.

It should then look like this:

[image]